# Why does my flutter app keep crashing when loading pdf from the internet?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am building an app in flutter that reads pdf files from the internet. The package I'm using is "advance_pdf_viewer." I have followed everything as instructed in the documentation. But my app always crashes a few seconds after showing the Circular Progress Indicator Widget.

Here's is my code

```
//@dart=2.9
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:advance_pdf_viewer/advance_pdf_viewer.dart';

class PDFviewerPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const PDFviewerPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PDFviewerPageState createState() => _PDFviewerPageState();
}

class _PDFviewerPageState extends State<PDFviewerPage> {
  bool _isLoading = true;
  PDFDocument _document;

  loadDocument() async {
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
    });
    final document = await PDFDocument.fromURL(
        "https://unec.edu.az/application/uploads/2014/12/pdf-sample.pdf");
    setState(() {
      _document = document;
      _isLoading = false;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadDocument();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Example'),
      ),
      body: _isLoading
          ? const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
          : PDFViewer(document: _document),
    );
  }
}
```

Also, I have these permissions enabled in my manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

This is the error message returned in my debug console
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getPage on channel flutter_plugin_pdf_viewer)

What could be the cause of the consistent crashing? And how do I fix it?

Comment: add some error logs

Comment: Attach a debugger and get some error messages ...

Comment: @griffins This is the error [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getPage on channel flutter_plugin_pdf_viewer)

Comment: @derpirscher
This is the error [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getPage on channel flutter_plugin_pdf_viewer)

Comment: Did you already try running 'flutter clean' and restarting the app? Maybe this page (with similar MissingPluginException error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62064524/missingpluginexceptionno-implementation-found-for-method

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue, the only thing that worked for me so far was using the previous version of the package:

(on pubspec.yaml)

```
advance_pdf_viewer: 2.0.0
```

Comment: I actually used another but similar package which seems hassle-free. flutter_pdfview: ^1.2.1

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it is still actual. Here is what I have tried, according to https://github.com/lohanidamodar/pdf_viewer/issues/117#issuecomment-1259538440 temporary solution could be updating `pubspec.yaml` file with the following changes:

**Replace the following line:**

```
advance_pdf_viewer: ^2.0.1
```

**with:**

```
  advance_pdf_viewer:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/lohanidamodar/pdf_viewer.git
      ref: 4e5d96be29de515f1081c0b6897741b8dca84722
```

**Moreover**, there is also another solution using https://pub.dev/packages/advance_pdf_viewer_fork package which doesn't have current issue.

Answer (score 1):

I actually solved the issue by replacing the package to flutter_pdfview: ^1.2.1